# Does Flash Player work on Android 5 with Firefox 48

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, adobe-flash

I have an Amazon Fire (KFFOWI) with CM12.1 installed and have Firefox as my browser. I have installed the archive flash player [11.1.115.81](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/11.1.115.81/install_flash_player_ics.apk) but, when I try to use it, all I get is *"A plugin is required to display this content"*.

I've read many things that suggest that it should work but they are probably stale and out of date.

So, as of October 2016, does the Flash player work on Android 5.1 and, if so, how does one get it working?

Comment: Firefox for Android won't use the flash player anymore (very early versions did). Some lesser known browsers support flash the way Firefox did (eg. FlashFox)

Comment: thanks for that. I ended up installing [Dolphin](http://dolphin.com) which seems to work.

Comment: @GiantTree You should post this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe does not support Flash on Android [beyond 4.0](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/06/flash-player-and-android-update.html) but that does not mean that it won't work. The last available version is [11.1](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/11.1.115.81/install_flash_player_ics.apk) which is [not on Google Play](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/06/flash-player-and-android-update.html) so must be [sideloaded](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installing-flash-player-android-devices.html) from the [Flash Player Archive](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html).

Flash support in Firefox is [being phased out](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2016/07/20/reducing-adobe-flash-usage-in-firefox/) and Chrome [also](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-dev/HTML5$20by$20default/chromium-dev/0wWoRRhTA_E/__E3jf40OAAJ). Other browsers, like [Dolphin](http://dolphin.com/download/), continue to support Flash and work with the [plugin](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/11.1.115.81/install_flash_player_ics.apk) installed from the [archive](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/android/11.1.115.81/install_flash_player_ics.apk).